# pKa vs range in choice of an indicator

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, titration

When choosing the ideal indicator during a titration, there are two considerations to keep in mind:

1. The pH = pKa of the equivalence point
2. The indicator has a small range (<±1) over which it can change color

Which factor is more important when deciding over two indicators to see which is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pH = pKa of the equivalence point.
it is the best factor to decided during the titration .
because if the range of the indicator is less , then we can't find the correct volume used in titration.this factor should be considered but not most affective one.